logic puzzle birth year
Suppose we have two people A and B. A died 129 years after B was born. At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years. B died in 30 B.C. When was A born?
This confused me. If B lived 100 years, B would be born in 130 BC and so A died in 1 BC but could be born at any point prior. If A lived 100 years, A would be born 29 years after B was born but since we don't know when B is born in this case we have no idea when A is born. Am I missing something obvious or is the question flawed?
Edit: I interpreted the statement "At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years" to mean that at least one of A or B died at the age of 100. Given this interpretation the problem is unsolvable (as discussed below). The interpretation that allows for an answer, however, is that there were precisely 100 different years in which A, B or both were alive (e.g. A was alive from 400BC to 350BC and B was alive from 1900 to 1950).

@fleablood see my answer.  It is true that B's year of birth is unknown, but that is irrelevant.

@fleablood : suppose that A was born just as B died.  Then, since A died 129 years after B was born, there would have been exactly 129 years where either A or B was alive.  Therefore, since there was only 100 years where either A or B was alive, there must be a 29 year gap from the time of B's death, to the time of A's birth, when neither A nor B was alive.

tl;dr.  So... to recap:  There was misinterpretation of what "At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years" means.  The OP and I both initially interpreted to mean "one of $A$ or $B$ lived exactly $100$ years".  By that interpretation problem has no solution and the OP and my reasoning was not in error. But if it is interpreted as "There were exactly 100 years (maybe not consecutively) where one or the other (or maybe both) were alive" then the solution is $A$ was born in $1BC$. ... No-one was wrong but people were confused in interpretation.

Since A died 129 years after B was born, and at least one of A,B was alive for exactly 100 years, there must have been a gap of exactly $~129 - 100 = 29~$ years, from the time B died until A was born.
So, A was born in 1 BC.

Alternative Explanation
Suppose that A was born just as B died.
Then, since A died 129 years after B was born, there would have been exactly 129 years where either A or B was alive.
Therefore, since there was only 100 years where either A or B was alive, there must be a 29 year gap from the time of B's death, to the time of A's birth, when neither A nor B was alive.

@fleablood Your counter example is in error.  Assuming that B lived 100 years, then A was born in 1 BC, and died in 1 BC, and so lived for  $~0~$ years.

@james Not true, because you are given that there was exactly 100 years, when A or B was alive.  So, since B lived 100 years, A must have lived $~0~$ years.

No. They don't need to live a cumulative 100 years. That would make the problem much easier. "At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years" means one of them lived for 100 years the other could've lived for who knows how long.

Oh. Maybe I've just misinterpreted the "At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years." I guess you could read it as you have (cumulative 100 years). I read it as: one guy lived for exactly 100 years (he was 100 years old).

@james Yes, that is how I am interpreting the problem, and I strongly suspect that this interpretation represents the problem composer's intent.

Yep you must be right otherwise it's unsolvable. Thanks!

@fleablood See all of the subsequent comments, following my answer.

Hmmm.... I think you user2661923 is interpreting " At least one of A or B was alive for exactly 100 years" as there were only $100$ years total where one or the other or both were alive.  In my opinion that is a very weird and unnatural way to interpret it.  If that was what the original puzzle meant, it should have been better expressed in my opinion.

@fleablood I completely agree.  This is another instance of brevity is the soul of poorly written math problems.  However, if you look at the situation from the problem composer's viewpoint, the more clearly that the problem is re-worded, the less of a challenge the problem is to solve, because the problem solver is then steered towards focusing on the gap between B's death and A's birth.  This perhaps explains why the problem composer left the problem so poorly worded.

Then again it's a hard concept to express.  I'd say something like "There were 100 years where one or the other was alive".  Of course that informally implies their lifespans overlapped.  Maybe I'd be perverse and say "Before either was born neither were alive and after both died neither were alive. However in the history of the planet there were exactly $100$ years where one, or the other, or both were alive."  That's kind of perversely overwritten but hopefully less ambiguous.
